# SQL select statement combining with different tables

Tags: sql, sap-ase

say I have three tables: `TableA`, `TableB`, and `TableC`. Each of these tables have a column: `ColA`.

`TableA` is my main table and `TableA.ColA` has a value.

I wish to check either `TableB` or `TableC` has also a value in their `ColA` that corresponds with my `TableA.ColA`.

So my statement is:

```
select count(*) 
 from TableA, TableB, TableC
where ( TableA.ColA = TableB.ColA AND TableA.ColA = "ABC")  
   OR ( TableA.ColA = TableC.ColA AND TableA.ColA = "ABC" )
```

But this does not work.

If my `TableB.ColA` doesn't have a `ColA` value and `TableC.ColA` has a value, the result returned is still `0`. I should get a count of `1` back.

What is wrong with my select statement?

My TableA data:

```
ColA
-----
ABC
```

My TableB data:

```
ColA
----
NULL
```

My TableC data:

```
ColA
----
ABC
```

Because `TableC.ColA` and `TableA.ColA` has the same value, it should return me a count of `1`. But it is not doing so. My database is SAP ASE

thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to count exactly.  You'd have to also show us some sample data, and your expected result when querying that data.

Comment: And it's always useful to specify which database you are using.

Comment: It's almost always to specify the database.  For this question, it doesn't matter.

Comment: never, ever, ever under any circumstances do coma joins.

Comment: @MK As with any rule, there are exceptions, though extremely rare.

Comment: @Andreas uh. such as?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing `INNER JOIN` and you need `OUTER JOIN` or `EXISTS`. Syntax will vary for RDBMS you are using.

Try this:

```
SELECT    COUNT(*)
    FROM
        TableA A
    WHERE
        A.ColA = "Value"
        AND (
            EXISTS(
                SELECT * FROM TableB 
                    WHERE
                        ColA = "Value"
            )
            OR EXISTS(
                SELECT * FROM TableC
                    WHERE
                        ColA = "Value"            
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

```sql
select count(*) 
 from TableA
      LEFT JOIN
      TableB
      ON TableA.ColA = TableB.ColA
      LEFT JOIN
      TableC
      ON TableA.ColA = TableC.ColA
where TableA.ColA = "Value"
      AND
      (TableB.ColA IS NOT NULL OR TableC.ColA IS NOT NULL)
```

The idea here is:

1. Use `LEFT JOIN` so that the row is generated whether or not `TableB` or `TableC` has a row for it. If one of them or both don't have it, corresponding values will be `NULL`
2. Filter out rows for which neither `TableB` nor `TableC` have those values by requiring that at least one of them is not `NULL` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Hah. I wrote the same query after OP said about Sybase.

Comment: What is the performance difference between using this solution and the one by Ingaz? thanks

Comment: @PangSerLark Performance is likely very similar, but result (count) will be different if `TableB` or `TableC` can have multiple rows for `ColA`. The `EXISTS` version will count the A records only, while the `LEFT JOIN` version will count the number of A * B * C records, e.g. if A has 3 rows, B has 5 rows and C and 7 rows, for with given ColA value, you get the cartesian join count of 3 * 5 * 7 = 105.